# Gauge problem - Lagrangian for a massless particle in FRW

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism

The Lagrangian of a massless particle in a Freedman-Robertson metric has to be invariant under reparametrization of the world-line.
Unfortunately the Euler-Lagrange equations give a non linear relation for the time parameter and the free one, which strongly depends on the factor scale: if I choose the free parameter for the world-line, I also define the factor scale and this is physically inconsistent.
I have postulated the simplest Lagrangian, a Lagrange parameter times the constraint: what is the origin of this inconsistency?

Comment: Can you clarify if your action is an integral over worldline or spacetime? Not doing EH+massless scalar?

Comment: The action is over the world-line.

Comment: If I fix the time coordinate linear in the free parameter , I found inconsistency in the Lagrangian of a massless particle, why?